# db2admin does not have the privilege to grant option?

Tags: ms-access, odbc, db2, ms-access-2007

I am using db2 9.7.2 (express) version. Trying to connect the db2 via ODBC to MS Office 2007. connection all worked well but when try to open table from access error saying db2admin user does not have previlage for the operation...

I has done the typical installation of db2.. so Is there anything more to do for user right ?.. db2/msoffice works good. Only thing with the access right...

please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Who created the database (owns DBADB profile) and who created the instance (SYSADMIN profile)?
Probably, you created a database with a different user to db2admin, and for this database the user db2admin does not have special privileges.

Check the groups in you operative system, the sysadmin_grp group in the instance, and who created the database. The problem could be solve just by adding db2admin in a operative system group (db2admins).

If db2admin could connect to the database, because the connection grant is public, but the data access is restricted to some users. Just by adding dbadm to db2admin or giving the profile sysadmin, then db2admin will have the complete control of the database.

Comment: sorry for the delay... actualy that error stopped once we put a password to operating system user which we used to log in and installed the db2. This tip we got from surfing the web. Thank you very much for the help.